# Prove that sum of 2 simple bivectors in $R^{4}$ is not necessarily a simple bivector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-algebras

> Prove that sum of 2 simple bivectors in $R^{4}$ and other higher dimensional spaces is not necessarily a simple bivector and show that $B^{2}$ is not a scalar?

I want to show that $B$ does not have a specific property of a bivector.
 note: $B=e_1 \land e_2 +e_3 \land e_4$. 
 I am having problems figuring this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$B^2 = BB = (e_1\wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4)(e_1\wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) = (e_1e_2 + e_3e_4)(e_1e_2 + e_3e_4) \\ = e_1e_2e_1e_2 + e_1e_2e_3e_4 + e_3e_4e_1e_2 + e_3e_4e_3e_4 = -1+I+I-1= -2+2I$$ which is not a scalar.  Thus $B$ cannot be a simple bivector (i.e. $2$-blade).

Comment: so $B=e_1e_2 +e_3e_4$?

Comment: Yes.  $e_1e_2 = e_1\cdot e_2 +e_1\wedge e_2 = 0 + e_1\wedge e_2 = e_1\wedge e_2$.  And likewise for $e_3e_4$.